# React - styling in component with javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to adapt this [Codepen loading animation](https://codepen.io/chrisgannon/pen/bEKbNg), which has the triad [markup, style and logic] and use it as an exportable react component.

For that I try to import css from `css` file, export javascript functions form `js` file, and render `html` in a `<div>` within my component.

---

This is the code I have so far:

**Loading.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/clock.css';
import * from './js/clock.js';

class Loading extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="container">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
              <title>clock coffee cup</title>
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="cupMask">
                    <path className="cupMask" d="M215.65,214.41c0,19.85,37.76,35.94,84.35,35.94s84.35-16.09,84.35-35.94H506V399H145V214.41h70.65Z" fill="#ff0d0d"/>
                </clipPath>
                <clipPath id="handleMask">
                    <path className="handleMask" fill="#4BFF00" d="M475,305c-23.7-2.4-104.6,3.9-104.6,3.9s12.1-11.9,13.9-46.2c0,0,2.3-39.9,0-48.3
                    c9.9,0,90.6,0,90.6,0V305z"/>
                </clipPath>    
              </defs>
              <g className="cupGroup">

                  <ellipse className="ripple" cx="300" cy="214.41" rx="84.35" ry="35.94" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="6"/>
                  <ellipse className="ripple" cx="300" cy="214.41" rx="84.35" ry="35.94" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="6"/>    
                <g clipPath="url(#cupMask)">
                      <path id="base" d="M216,214v48.7
                c0,46.4,37.8,84.4,84.2,84.4h-0.3c46.4,0,84.1-38,84.1-84.4V214" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>
                </g>
                <g clipPath="url(#handleMask)">
                  <path opacity="1" id="handle" d="M384.5,228.7c15.9,0,27.8,13.6,27.8,31.5s-14.9,30.5-30.8,30.5" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>
                </g>    
                <ellipse id="rim" cx="300" cy="214.41" rx="84.35" ry="35.94" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>
              </g>
            <g className="clockGroup" opacity="1">
            <line id="bighand" fill="none" strokeWidth="14" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" x1="300" y1="263" x2="300" y2="189"/>
            <line id="littlehand" fill="none" strokeWidth="14" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" x1="300" y1="263" x2="300" y2="221"/>                 
              </g>
              <line id="table" x1="235" y1="376" x2="365" y2="376" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>                 
            </svg>


            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Loading;
```

**clock.css**

```
body {
  background-color:#FFF9ED;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  position:absolute;
  width:600px;

}

svg{
  visibility:hidden;

}

line, ellipse, path{
  stroke:#574227;
}
```

**clock.js**

```
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
  select = function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s);
  },
  selectAll = function(s) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(s);
  },
  container = select('.container'),
  cupGroup = select('.cupGroup'),
    littlehand = select('#littlehand'),
    bighand = select('#bighand'),
    cupColour = '#574227',
  clockColour = '#70A0A0',
    rippleColour = '#AD834E'

//center the container cos it's pretty an' that
TweenMax.set(container, {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  xPercent: -50,
  yPercent: -50
})
TweenMax.set('svg', {
  visibility: 'visible'
})
TweenMax.set([littlehand, bighand],{
  transformOrigin:'50% 100%'
})

export function makeAnimation(){
  var tl = new TimelineMax({delay:2, onComplete:makeAnimation});
  tl.to('#rim', 1, {
    attr:{
      ry:84.35
    },
    stroke:clockColour
  })
  .to('#base', 1, {
    y:-47.5,
    stroke:clockColour
  },'-=1')
  .to('#table', 0.8, {
    drawSVG:'40% 60%',
    alpha:0
  },'-=1')
  .to('#handle', 0.3, {
    x:-50,
    stroke:clockColour,
    ease:Power1.easeIn
  },'-=1')
  .to(cupGroup, 1, {
    y:36,
    ease:Back.easeOut
  },'-=1')
  .fromTo([bighand,littlehand], 1, {
    drawSVG:'-1% -1%',
    y:20
  },
    {
    y:0,
    stroke:clockColour,
    drawSVG:'0% 70%',
    ease:Back.easeOut

  },'-=0.6')
  /* .to([littlehand, bighand], 0.1, {
        rotation:0               
    }) */
  .addCallback(setClock,'+=0.4')

  .to([bighand], 2, {
    rotation:0,
    ease:Power1.easeInOut,
    delay:5
  })
    .to([littlehand], 2, {
    rotation:-360,
    ease:Power1.easeInOut
  },'-=2')
  .to([bighand,littlehand], 0.6, {
    drawSVG:'-1% -1%',
    y:-40,
    stroke:cupColour,
    ease:Back.easeIn
  })
  .to('#rim', 1, {
    attr:{
      ry:35.94
    },
    stroke:cupColour,
  },'-=0.6')
  .to('#base', 1, {
    y:0,
    stroke:cupColour,
  },'-=1')

  .to(cupGroup, 1, {
    y:0,
    ease:Back.easeInOut
  },'-=1')
  .to('#handle', 0.6, {
    x:0,
    stroke:cupColour,
  },'-=0.6')
  .staggerFromTo('.ripple', 3, {
    attr:{
      rx:0,
      ry:0
    },
    stroke:'#f7f7f7'
  },{
    attr:{
      rx:84,
      ry:36 
    },
    alpha:1,
    stroke:rippleColour

  },0.4,'-=0.6')
  .to('#table', 0.5, {
    drawSVG:'0% 100%',
    alpha:1
  },'-=3.4')


  tl.timeScale(1.8)  

}

//ScrubGSAPTimeline(tl);
//tl.progress(1)

export function setClock(){

    TweenMax.set([littlehand, bighand], {
      rotation:0               
  })
    //new date reference every minute
    var myDate = new Date();

    //hours minutes and seconds from Date object
    var hours = myDate.getHours();
    var minutes = myDate.getMinutes();
    var seconds = myDate.getSeconds();

    //minute position calculation
    var minuteValue = minutes*6;
    TweenMax.to(bighand,1.2, {
      shortRotation:minuteValue,
      ease:Back.easeOut.config(0.6)
    });

    //hour position calculation
    var hourValue = hours*30 +(minutes/2);         
    TweenMax.to(littlehand,1.2, {
      shortRotation:hourValue
    });



}

makeAnimation();
```

at `index.html`, I link `javascript` settings required from codepen page, like so:

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js">
    <link href="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/35984/ScrubGSAPTimeline.js">
    <link href="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/DrawSVGPlugin.js?r=12">
    <link type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!--     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-media-player/dist/react-media-player.js"></script> -->

    <title>App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
<!--     <style>
    body {background-color: #C86428;
          background-image: url("bg.png");
          background-position: 0 5;
          opacity: 1.0;
          height: 120vh;}
    </style> -->
    <style>
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,400);
      html, body {background:rgb(223,189,150);
                  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
                  margin: 0px;
                  padding: 0px;
                  line-height:2.5em;}
      h1 {
          margin:0;
      }
    </style>

    <div id="root">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

in my **App.jsx** I import the component:

```
import Page from './components/Page';
```

and render it like so:

```
<Route exact path='/page' render={() => (
   <Page
   />
)} />
```

and finally in **Page.jsx** I import **Loading.jsx**, like so:

```
import Loading from './Loading.jsx';
```

this is my project structure:

```
public/
      index.html
      js/
src/
   App.jsx
   index.js
   components/
             Page.jsx
             Loading.jsx
             css/
                clock.css
             js/
               clock.js
```

---

Nothing is being rendered, though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your App.jsx file?

Comment: it's huge. any particular section of it?

Comment: If App is your entry file (used in index.html, usually as id="root") you need to import <Loading/> somewhere. That part would help

Comment: where are you importing your  Loading  component ?

Comment: please refer to edit.I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you look at the settings of that codepen?  This script relies on tweenmax, gsap and drawsvg javascript libraries to work and one of the very css rules you have is that your svg's visibility is set to hidden.

Comment: no I havent....should I point to these libraries at index.html?

Comment: Two things:
  a)   import * from './js/clock.js'; should be import * as clock from './js/clock.js
  b)   certain properties of eclipse need to be written in correct format e.g. 'stroke-linecap' should be 'strokeLinecap' and 'stroke-miterlimit' by 'strokeMiterlimit, etc it is suggested in browser console.

After fixing this it works for me without any errors. Rest is dependent on how you are using the loading component as suggested by @Rasnick

Comment: I did as you suggested, but console warns me that 'clock' is not being used and I still get no style rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few edits you have to make.

**You are using link tags to load javascript. You need to change to `script` tag.**

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js">
```

**clock.js depends on the rendered dom element**. You should not let the script run before the DOM is rendered. Use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to load the script.

You can use dynamic imports if its a self executing script. In this case you might need to prefix all the global variables with `window.`. For example `window.TweenMax`, `window.Power1`, `window.Back`

```
componentDidMount(){
        import("./js/clock.js");
 }
```

**OR**

You can change the script to export a default function and run the function in `componentDidMount`

```
export default () => {
  //All the clock.js code
makeAnimation();
}
```

And use as

```
import makeAnimation from "./js/clock";

class Loading extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        makeAnimation();
    }
```

[Demo using this approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zkx1cc)

**OR**

Pure DOM Manipulation (In case of an external script).

```
componentDidMount(){
             fetch("url").then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = text;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

You can run the stack snippet below to see the animation in effect.

```js
class Loading extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
             fetch("https://codepen.io/nithinthampi/pen/JjjOQVv.js").then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = text;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="container">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
              <title>clock coffee cup</title>
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="cupMask">
                    <path className="cupMask" d="M215.65,214.41c0,19.85,37.76,35.94,84.35,35.94s84.35-16.09,84.35-35.94H506V399H145V214.41h70.65Z" fill="#ff0d0d"/>
                </clipPath>
                <clipPath id="handleMask">
                    <path className="handleMask" fill="#4BFF00" d="M475,305c-23.7-2.4-104.6,3.9-104.6,3.9s12.1-11.9,13.9-46.2c0,0,2.3-39.9,0-48.3
                    c9.9,0,90.6,0,90.6,0V305z"/>
                </clipPath>    
              </defs>
              <g className="cupGroup">

                  <ellipse className="ripple" cx="300" cy="214.41" rx="84.35" ry="35.94" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="6"/>
                  <ellipse className="ripple" cx="300" cy="214.41" rx="84.35" ry="35.94" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="6"/>    
                <g clipPath="url(#cupMask)">
                      <path id="base" d="M216,214v48.7
                c0,46.4,37.8,84.4,84.2,84.4h-0.3c46.4,0,84.1-38,84.1-84.4V214" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>
                </g>
                <g clipPath="url(#handleMask)">
                  <path opacity="1" id="handle" d="M384.5,228.7c15.9,0,27.8,13.6,27.8,31.5s-14.9,30.5-30.8,30.5" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>
                </g>    
                <ellipse id="rim" cx="300" cy="214.41" rx="84.35" ry="35.94" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>
              </g>
            <g className="clockGroup" opacity="1">
            <line id="bighand" fill="none" strokeWidth="14" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" x1="300" y1="263" x2="300" y2="189"/>
            <line id="littlehand" fill="none" strokeWidth="14" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" x1="300" y1="263" x2="300" y2="221"/>                 
              </g>
              <line id="table" x1="235" y1="376" x2="365" y2="376" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeWidth="14"/>                 
            </svg>


            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Loading />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#FFF9ED;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  position:absolute;
  width:600px;

}

svg{
  visibility:hidden;

}

line, ellipse, path{
  stroke:#574227;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
```

**Note that all the plugins you are using are not open-sourced.**

https://codepen.io/GreenSock/full/OPqpRJ/

Answer (score 1):

This is because script `clock.js` excute before `Loading` Component mount into the dom. `container = select('.container')` and `cupGroup = select('.cupGroup')` will get null. So noting is being rendered on the page.

You should excute the script in `clock.js` in lifecyle `componentDidMount`.

clock.js

```
export funtion initClock() {
    // write the script in clock.js here
}
```

Loading.jsx

```
import {initClock} from '.js/clock.js'

class Loading extends Component {
    render() {}
    componentDidMount() {
        initClock();      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import your style to page like:

```
import clockCSS from 'styles/App.module.css';
```

In the page you can assign styleclass as:

```
className={clockCSS.container}
```

In the style.css file you have to update the way of defining styleclasses:

```
:local(.container){
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
}
```